# Chef: Two contradicting not_if powershell guard statements evaluating to true

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe

So I am working with chef and need to chain some resources together if a precondition is true. I need to check if the version of a process is what I want it to be if so do things. I was seeing odd behavior and was noticing that my guard statements are not being evaludated in the way I would expect. So I made this tests

```
log 'log_version' do
    message 'Peregrin Took'
    level :error
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    not_if <<-EOH
    (C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe --version) -Like '*1.7.2*'
    EOH
end


log 'log_version' do
    message 'Meriadoc Brandybuck'
    level :error
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    not_if <<-EOH
    (C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe --version) -NotLike '*1.7.2*'
    EOH
end
```

And when I run this I get

```
   Recipe: win-telegraf::telegraf
     * log[log_version] action write[2018-07-24T07:31:42-07:00] INFO: Processing log[log_version] action write (win-telegraf::telegraf line 47)
   [2018-07-24T07:31:42-07:00] INFO: Processing powershell_script[Guard resource] action run (dynamically defined)
   [2018-07-24T07:31:43-07:00] ERROR: Peregrin Took


     * log[log_version] action write[2018-07-24T07:31:43-07:00] INFO: Processing log[log_version] action write (win-telegraf::telegraf line 57)
   [2018-07-24T07:31:43-07:00] INFO: Processing powershell_script[Guard resource] action run (dynamically defined)
   [2018-07-24T07:31:43-07:00] ERROR: Meriadoc Brandybuck
```

Why are both of these statements logging? When I run these powershell snippets in the vm I get one returning true and the other returning false. So I would expect only one log line to write. But when I run both of them are writing.

After doing some reading it seems that the guard statement makes its decision off the `$LASTEXITCODE` and in the case of my statement both will have a `$LASTEXITCODE` of 0

[image]

So I have tried changing my guard statement to force an exit code of something other than 0

```
log 'log_version' do
    message 'Peregrin Took'
    level :error
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    not_if <<-EOH
    if((C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe --version) -Like '*1.7.2*') { exit 1 }
    EOH
end


log 'log_version opposite' do
    message 'Meriadoc Brandybuck'
    level :error
    guard_interpreter :powershell_script
    not_if <<-EOH
    if((C:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe --version) -NotLike '*1.7.2*') { exit 1 }
    EOH
end
```

Though this has not changed results and I am still seeing both log resources executed.

Comment: What happens if the statement is `exit 0` and `exit 1`? exit codes of 0 are usually interpreted as success, anything else is error. i.e. let's make sure that the running of PowerShell works in the way you think it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got a working guard, the issue was with the space in `Program Files` and the `--version` being interpreted as Powershell code. by making my guard string like this

```
"(&'c:\\Program Files\\telegraf\\telegraf.exe' --version) -like '*#{node['windows']['telegraf']['version']}*'"
```

By single quoting the path the path was correctly interpreted by powershell, and I needed the `&` operator so that the string in the parentheses was interpreted like a commandlet.